# how do i define a struct where the keys are ascending integers without a defined limit?

Tags: go, types

this is an issue I have run into before and i am not sure how to solve this cleanly.

i have json_data that looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "0": {
            "first_name": "hello",
            "last_name": "world"
        },
        "1": {
            "first_name": "hello",
            "last_name": "world"
        }
    }]
}
```

the thing is, the amount of items in this list is undefined. The keys are always uninterrupted and the order matters which is why they are there.

how would i represent this as a struct? in Typescript i mihght type it as [key: str]: {...} but I dont know how to do it in go.

Comment: Use a map. You cannot use a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would i represent this as a struct? in Typescript ...

This is a common stumbling block for those learning go after exeperience with interpreted languages such as typescript or python, so a good thing to get ironed out right away.

In those other languages, user defined objects are represented by the same underlying type containing hash maps to dynamically associate attribute and method names with underlying values and functions.  Thus an attribute can be added to an object at any time as it is really just a dynamic collection anyway.

In Go, struct fields are *static*.  The fields are defined within the source code at compile time, and should be accessed with the dot operator by name. Field names are *symbols*, not *variables*.

In Go, you *never* treat structs like dynamically defined sets of key/value pairs.  Structs only make sense when there is a well defined set of keys that can reasonably be turned into symbols in the code.

Your data structure in json is a little silly looking (if the keys are ascending integers, that's just a *list*) but assuming that's not up to you, I'd suggest you model something like this.

```
type name struct {
    First_name, Last_name string
}
type fulldata struct {
    Data []map[string]name
}
```

Working example here: https://go.dev/play/p/gBtrRoceeTL

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately i need the keys, they map to something else and that object might not start with zero. For example it could start with 6, so the only way to index nicely is if my json also has keys like that.

Comment: Sure, the use case is the most important motivation for the structure.